# Autocomplete Internal Server 500

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

This is my view page containing my scripts this is where i declare my autocomplete script and my script  where I get the information from the web service

```
@model IEnumerable<BarclaysApp.Models.Stadiums>

@section Scripts
           {


    <script src="~/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="~/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions")',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.value);
                        $("#ResultsDiv").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        function DoSearch() {
            $("#resultsDiv").html("");
            var key = { "key": $("#searchString").val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Stadium.asmx/GetStadiumByName",
                data: JSON.stringify(key),
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (result, textStatus) {
                    if (textStatus == "success") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                            $("#resultsDiv").html($("#resultsDiv").html() + result.d[i] + "<br/>");
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (result, status, error) {
                    $("#resultsDiv").html("Error: " + error + " <br/>")
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Stadiums</h2>

<div class="jumbotron">

    <div>
        <input id="SearchString" type="text" placeholder="Stadium" />
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="DoSearch();" />
    </div>
    <div id="resultsDiv"></div>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Capacity)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Team)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Capacity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.stadiumID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.stadiumID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.stadiumID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

This is my webservice file this is where my get method used to display the stadium searched for by the user

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using BarclaysApp.Models;

namespace BarclaysApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Stadium
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Stadium : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetStadiumsByName(string term)
        {

            List<string> stadiumlist = new List<string>();
            if (term != "")
            {
                foreach (var Name in db.Stadiums
                                        .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(term))
                                        .ToList())
                {
                   stadiumlist.Add(Name.Name);
                }
            }

            return stadiumlist.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

My autocomplete works but when i go to search i get Error: Internal Server Error 500

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the first line of `GetStadiumsByName` and inspected the value of term and stepped through to find out where an exception gets thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the AJAX request to GET. Good practices say that GET is recommended for reading data and POST is used to send information (write operations) into the server.